# Using MSXML2.XMLHTTP in access VBA not extracting all page data

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, ms-access-2013

Currently, we are using below mentioned code for data extraction but code is not extracting complete data from webpage, code is ignoring data which is visible when i enable java script and DOM storage on Internet explorer.

till now I use below mentioned code, trailing code is extracting every thing accept images from web page.

My code is given blow.

```vb
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    http.Send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.ResponseText

    On Error GoTo 0
    html1 = html.body.innerHTML
     brand5 = html.documentElement.innerHTML
     If html1 Like "*media__thumb*" Then
other_img = html.getElementsByClassName("media__thumb")(0).innerText
'other_img = other_img.innerHTML
End If
```

On webpage multiple image html code is given below(please note that my above code is not extracting data from below mentioned html code.

```html
            <a class="media__thumbnail" data-media_type="IMAGE" data-media_id="orbit-bagged-53017-64" data-target="IMAGE" data-has-index="true">
                <img src="https://images.yourweb/_145.jpg">
            </a>
            <a class="media__thumbnail media__thumbnail--selected" data-media_type="IMAGE" data-media_id="orbit-bagged-53017-e1" data-target="IMAGE" data-has-index="true">
                <img src="https://images.yourweb1_145.jpg">
            </a>
            </span></a>
```

http.response is given below

```
<div id="thumbnails" class="media__thumbnails" data-component="thumbnails"></div>

    <script type="text/template" id="media__thumbnails">
        {{#thumbnails}}
            <a class="media__thumbnail" data-media_type="{{type}}" data-media_id="{{id}}" data-target="{{type}}" data-has-index="true">
                <img src="{{{thumb}}}"/>
                {{# hasIcon}}
                  {{# threeSixtyIcon}} <div class="whitespace"><span class="threesixtyIcon"></span></div>{{/ threeSixtyIcon}}
                  {{^ threeSixtyIcon}} <span class="videoIcon"></span>{{/ threeSixtyIcon}}
                {{/ hasIcon}}
            </a>
        {{/thumbnails}}
        {{#additionalThumbnailsThumbnail}}
            <a class="media__thumbnail media__thumbnail-additional-count" data-media_type="{{type}}" data-media_id="{{id}}" data-target="{{type}}" data-has-index="true">
                <img src="{{{thumb}}}"/>
                {{# hasIcon}}
                  {{# threeSixtyIcon}} <div class="whitespace"><span class="threesixtyIcon"></span></div>{{/ threeSixtyIcon}}
                  {{^ threeSixtyIcon}} <span class="videoIcon"></span>{{/ threeSixtyIcon}}
                {{/ hasIcon}}
                {{#additionalImagesCount}}
                    <div class="media__thumbnail-overlay"></div>
                    <span class="media__thumbnail-count">+{{additionalImagesCount}}</span>
                {{/additionalImagesCount}}
            </a>
```

Comment: Please specify URL or post `http.ResponseText` HTML content, so that other could reproduce the issue.

Comment: ^^ please include url

Comment: http.response updated please

Comment: did you check http.response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That content required javascript to run on the page so you will need to either:

1. Search for the information for those part of those urls in the web traffic to see if you obtain from elsewhere (you can - shown below); or,
2. Automate a browser e.g. with microsoft internet controls

You can see from the following that the content is loaded dynamically:

```html
 <script type="text/template" id="media__thumbnails">
        {{#thumbnails}}
            <a class="media__thumbnail" data-media_type="{{type}}" data-media_id="{{id}}" data-target="{{type}}" data-has-index="true">
                <img src="{{{thumb}}}"/>
                {{# hasIcon}}
                  {{# threeSixtyIcon}} <div class="whitespace"><span class="threesixtyIcon"></span></div>{{/ threeSixtyIcon}}
                  {{^ threeSixtyIcon}} <span class="videoIcon"></span>{{/ threeSixtyIcon}}
                {{/ hasIcon}}
            </a>
        {{/thumbnails}}
        {{#additionalThumbnailsThumbnail}}
        ...... 
        {{/additionalThumbnails}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/template"
```

---

**1) Network tab - different url**

Using a different url found in network tab returning json containing links. Response is json so a [jsonparser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) is required.

```
'VBE>Tools> References> Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Download and add in jsonconverter.bas from https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas
```

Place the converter.bas code in module2 and comment out the line: `Attribute VB_Name = "JsonConverter"`

In module1 place the  `GetInfo` sub.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim json As Object, url1 As String, url2 As String, url3 As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.homedepot.com/p/svcs/frontEndModel/100001020?_=1556447908065", False
        .send
        Set json = Module2.ParseJson(.responseText)
    End With
    'Parse json object (see paths shown below for example)
     url1 = json("primaryItemData")("media")("mediaList")(2)("location")
     url2 = json("primaryItemData")("media")("mediaList")(3)("location")
     url3 = json("primaryItemData")("media")("mediaList")(4)("location")   'example
    Stop '<==delete me later
End Sub
```

Paths to first 3 thumbnails:

```
json►primaryItemData►media►mediaList►2►location
json►primaryItemData►media►mediaList►3►location
json►primaryItemData►media►mediaList►4►location
```

Explore json [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=47ac04c438d347deb3b098e8befd15a9).

---

**2) Automated browser (IE version):**

```
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetImageLinks()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, images As Object, i As Long
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-Sandstone-Rock-Valve-Box-Cover-53017/100001020"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set images = .document.querySelectorAll(".media__thumbnail img")

        For i = 0 To images.Length - 1
            Debug.Print images.item(i).src
        Next

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you check your code in access vba because after importing jsonconverter i am still facing error on following line.json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)

Comment: i place code in module 2 and also currently first row in comment and in module 1 getinfo code.but still same keys error on following line.json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)

Comment: please upload now,i am available

Comment: please upload file now

Comment: now code execution is successful but no output,kindly how to get urls..thanks

Comment: thanks dear,last question,how to save output in text file or in variable so that value will be used later..thanks

Comment: dear AHarr,can you please tell me json url for this url https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0152VYPXY

Comment: please open a new question

Comment: check now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56037729/json-values-extraction-from-webpage-using-msxml2-xmlhttp