# JSON values extraction from webpage using MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently i am able to extract values from webpage but facing issue json value extraction.

I am using following code for other values extraction.

```
On Error Resume Next
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", url1234, False
    http.Send
    html.body.innerHTML = http.ResponseText
    brand = html.body.innerText
    'MsgBox (brand)
```

Above code is not extracting following values of this url

```
"" : {"0":"B0037RYT96","1":"B0152VYOQ2","2":"B0152WOT70","3":"B003W0NYKS","4":"B0152WOT8Y","5":"B00C2O7M1M","6":"B0037RMS6W","7":"B0037RMI0S","8":"B0152VYPXY"},
```

Comment: i've updated answer with regex for your edited pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything I can see in your code that attempts to extract this.

You could use regex to specify the appropriate pattern to extract that string. Below, the string you are after is stored in `r` variable.

**EDIT:**

Given your edit to the required string you can change the regex to:

```
\"dimensionToAsinMap\" :(.*)[^\r\n].*
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Q1ecsq/1)

**Former answer:**

Try regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/9aRiNr/1)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim s As String, r As String, re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.yoursite.com?tag=stackoverfl08-20", False
        .send
        s = .responseText
    End With
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "(""dimensionToAsinMap"" :.(.|\n)*)[;^\r\n].*return dataToReturn"
        If .test(s) Then
            r = .Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            r = "No match"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Locals window check:**

[image]

---

**Regex explanation:**

[image]